# React Npm start failed

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, compiler-errors, portfolio

I cloned a react website and after installing modules I ran the app and I got this code below as an error of some sort
`aderRunner.js:111:13) at C:\Users\DELL\Documents\projects\potfolio\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ], library: 'digital envelope routines', reason: 'unsupported', code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED' }`

I have tried deleting the package-Jason-lock file and installing again but I have not gotten a solution